# Binomial Question with two probabilities

Tags: binomial-distribution

What we do if we were to figure out the probability of lets say, to pass a certain round of a quiz when there are 2 probabilities involved? Specifically, If in a round there were 2 Multiple choice question (4 choices in each) along with 5 True or false questions, and the contestant required at least 80% to pass that certain round... how would we determine that? Since there are 2 probabilities (0.5 and 0.25)

Would averaging the two be accurate? (0.5+0.35)/2?

Comment: Are you asking for the formula that gives you the probability of >2 successes out of 4 trials when the underlying probability of success differs by trial?

Comment: Are we to assume (a rather strong assumption) that the person completing the exam is completely guessing and that there is an equal chance of selecting any of the answers for each question?

Comment: No, averaging and treating as binomial is not generally the right approach.

Comment: Each type of question is worth the same?

Answer (score 1):

> there were 2 Multiple choice question (4 choices in each) along with 5 True or false questions, and the contestant required at least 80% to pass

$\geq$ 80% on 7 questions means getting 6 or 7 correct (0 or 1 wrong).

$P(0 \text{ wrong})$ is straightforward.

$P(\text{exactly 1 wrong})=P(\text{exactly 1 multiple choice &  0 T/F wrong})\\\qquad+P(\text{exactly 0 multiple choice &  1 T/F wrong})$

Can you do it from there?

More generally, you have to deal with breaking events down into cases where you have say $r$ right on multiple choice (binomial probability) and $s$ right on T/F (binomial probability), and the two events are independent.